# Having a binary vector with $N$ one coordinates, how many times a vector containing $M$ ones will appear?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Let vector $\mathbf{v}=(1,1,1,1,0)$. Using $\mathbf{v}$, the vectors that have the number of one coordinates equal to $3$ are given by the following subset: 
$\{(1,1,1,0,0);(1,1,0,1,0);(1,0,1,1,0);(0,1,1,1,0)\}$. Then, using this subset, the vectors that have the number of one coordinates equal to $2$ are:
$\{(1,1,0,0,0);(1,0,1,0,0);(0,1,1,0,0);;(1,1,0,0,0);(1,0,0,1,0);(0,1,0,1,0);;(1,0,1,0,0);(1,0,0,1,0);(0,0,1,1,0);;(0,0,1,1,0);(0,1,0,1,0);(0,0,1,1,0) \}$
In the second subset, we can see that for example vector $(1,1,0,0,0)$ is repeated $2$ times.

From this example (and many others..), I concluded that the number of times a vector containing $M$ ones that results from a binary vector with $N$ one coordinates will appear is given by:  $(N-M)!$.  Note that $M<N$.

Is it right? If yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the number of ones is decreasing in each step? If so, $M-N\lt0$?

Comment: Yes! (I will include this condition in my question).

Comment: That was not what I meant. I was trying to point out an inconsistency. $(M-N)!$ is the factorial of a negative number -- this is probably not what you mean?

Comment: I am sorry! I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting with $N$ ones. In each step, you pick one of them to remove. The order in which you remove them matters, since you're counting results as distinct if they contain the same pattern of ones but you arrived at them in different ways. Thus the number of ways you can remove ones until $M$ ones remain is

$$
N(N-1)\cdots(M+2)(M+1)=\frac{N!}{M!}\;,
$$

which is generally not equal to $(N-M)!$. In your example, $N=4$ and $M=2$, which yields $\frac{4!}{2!}=\frac{24}2=12$, which is indeed the number of results you listed, whereas your formula $(N-M)!$ yields $(4-2)!=2!=2$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The result is $2$ since I am considering just one vector ($(1,1,0,0,0)$ for ex.). Using the fact that your formula provides the total number of vectors, thus I think it suffices to divide this number by $\frac{N!}{(N-M)! M!}$, which gives the total number of vectors (combinations) without repetition, to get the number per vector; i.e. $(N-M)!$.

Comment: @mat: I see. Yes, you can complete it that way, but if that's what you were after, you can get it way easier: You want to remove $N-M$ particular ones, and you can remove them in any of the $(N-M)!$ possible orders.